# Is it possible to force hard application update (Ctrl + F5 browser analogue) from the app code in angular?

Tags: angular, browser, browser-cache

Sometimes my angular app gets updated.
The app is live already and some common scenario of usage is when the user doesn't close the browser tab with the application at all, so outdated version without checks could be used forever.

I've implemented a mechanism to check the app version on the back end side, so all calls from the outdated version are rejected.

The next step is to show the user some "Update required" dialog in case of such back end reject and in case of confirmation, it would be good not to force user press "Ctrl + F5" manually but to do it automatically from the app.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use response interceptor for the same when api call is rejected then on response interceptor section write window.reload

Comment: @YashRami  Is window.reload a hard refresh with cache cleaning?

Comment: No window.reload is not doing a hard refresh but 
 location.reload(true); is a refresh with cache cleaning.

Comment: @YashRami looks good, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to use interceptor to detect error and if error is detected then we reload page using the  window.location.reload(true); it will remove the cache and reload the page.

```
@Injectable()
export class myInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
     if (error.status === 404) {
      // Do your thing here      
     window.location.reload(true);
   }         
  }
```

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: What Observable should handleError return if it doesn't break the application workflow and passes execution next?

Comment: Here is the problem. Looks like catchError completely removes the error from the next handling while my app code also relies upon on receiving these errors. Is it possible to handle the error here (to update the app if it's some particular type of error) but to pass it next?

Comment: looks like I need return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(res => this.handleError(res))
    );

Comment: No if you did like this 

return next.handle(req).pipe( tap(res => this.handleError(res)) );
then every request it reload the page your requirement is reload the page when api is rejected

Comment: I was not talking about having the same handleError function. Of course, in reality, it will be much more complex.

Comment: @ArseniiFomin I just update my answer inside the handleError you can catch the specific error as i shown in the answer.

Comment: The problem is not related with status, I know how to handle statuses. It's related to the fact that other parts of the program stop to receive this error.

Comment: I've found that for my situation I need to use "return throwError(err);" in handleError(), this great article helped a lot: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

Comment: @ArseniiFomin Greatttt 